# How to get the forward url in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a page which will show special message when the previous route is routeA and next route is routeB. That means when I press the back button on browser it will take me to route A and forward button will take me to route B. Only in that situation the special message will be showed.

I am able to check if the previous URL was routeA by checking  `if(url()->previous()==route('routeA'))` and it is working.

Is there a method like `url()->next()==route('routeB')` which I can check in order to get the next route.

What I want is something like this,

```
if(url()->previous()==route('routeA')&&url()->next()==route('routeB'))
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Before redirect how you came to know next route. IF you have used middleware then terminate method can some how help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: I guess you create a `list by page feature` right? if so.. you then query in your controller how many pages do you have, and you can get what page is current, try to think to get the next page from that array in your controller and send that like var in your view

Comment: Also you can create a pagination and set `PerPage` method to display 1 and get next and previous Url really easy like `$results->previousPageUrl()`, and next like `$results->nextPageUrl()`. This is a manual [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods]